# Generic Extension Methods with Template Method

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I have an abstract class named OptionalParameters to be a base class for other parameter classes.

```
public abstract class OptionalParameter
{
    //Template Method 
    public string GenerateQueryString()
    {
        return OptionalParameterExtensions.GenerateQueryStringWithParameters<OptionalParameter>(this);
    }
}
```

And I have a base class as OptionalParameter. TimeEntriesParameters inherits from that base class.

```
public class TimeEntriesParameters : OptionalParameter
{
//Some Properties
}
```

So i want to generate a query string with my inherited classes properties. Then i wrote an extension method for that purpose.

```
public static class OptionalParameterExtensions
{
    public static string GenerateQueryStringWithParameters<T>(this T optionalParameters) where T : OptionalParameter
    {
        //Generates and returns query string with properties of T type
    }
}
```

After applying the structure stated above for the classes that inherits from base class with a usage stated below.

```
TimeEntriesParameters parameters = new TimeEntriesParameters();
string queryString = parameters.GenerateQueryString();
```

How can I create a generic template method for every OptionalParameter

EDIT: My real purpose is to read classes properties as below and then return a string like "?page=1&fromDate=20150728" etc.

```
public class TimeEntriesParameters : OptionalParameter
{
    [EntityOptionalParameter(ParameterName="page")]
    public int Page { get; set; }

    [EntityOptionalParameter(ParameterName = "fromDate")]
    public DateTime FromDate { get; set; }

    [EntityOptionalParameter(ParameterName = "fromTime")]
    public DateTime FromTime { get; set; }

    [EntityOptionalParameter(ParameterName = "ToDate")]
    public DateTime ToDate { get; set; }

    [EntityOptionalParameter(ParameterName = "ToTime")]
    public DateTime ToTime { get; set; }

    [EntityOptionalParameter(ParameterName = "SortOrder")]
    public Enumerations.SortOrder SortOrder { get; set; }

    [EntityOptionalParameter(ParameterName = "UserId")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
}
```

So i didn't want to write a method for every class to generate query string. I think I can put a template method in OptionalParameter base class and create the string by the class properties types and attribute properties.

Comment: `GenerateQueryStringWithParameters<this>(this);` would not compile. Also, why declare it as an extension-method when you call it statically?

Comment: It's orginal type was OptionalParameter. But i want to call this extension method for every class that inherits OptionalParameter abstract class. Actually my real purpose is to create a template method and call it generically.

Comment: What do you mean by "How can I create a generic template method for every OptionalParameter". Do you want each type inheriting from OptionalParameter to have its own `GenerateQueryStringWithParameters' method?

Comment: I want to use  GenerateQueryStringWithParameters method as a template method. Because I have an attribute with ParameterName property. In my template method I will look properties type then if property is not null then I will add a parameter to query string. Because of this I don't want to write their own methods for all types which inherits from OptionalParameter class.

Comment: @FernandoMatsumoto I have edited my question and put an example inherited class.

Comment: Sounds like `GenerateQueryStringWithParameters` should be an `abstract` method of `OptionalParameter`.  Each derived class can then override it to provide their own unique implementation.

Comment: @Servy I don't need to override the method, I think.I want to write a generic method for all classes that inherits from OptionalParameter Because I can decide which parameter should I add and what will its value from objects (inherited from OptionalParameter) reference, properties values and attributes properties.

Comment: @YusufDuyar but you *do* need to override the method because the information needed for the implementation *isn't* known from the `OptionalParameter` instance alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type parameter in `GenerateQueryStringWithParameters<T>()` is useless, since you're always calling the method as the type parameter `OptionalParameter`. You can therefore rewrite the method as `GenerateQueryStringWithParameters(this OptionalParemeter optionalParameter)`.

In order to generate the query string, you need to use reflection to loop through the properties in the class of `optionalParameter` and check if they have an `EntityOptionalParameter`. Assuming you can access the ParameterName through the property `EntityOptionalParameter.ParameterName`, you can do the following:

```
public static string GenerateQueryStringWithParameters(this OptionalParameter optionalParameter)
{
    var props = optionalParameter.GetType().GetProperties()
        .Select(x => new { Prop = x, Attr = x.GetCustomAttribute<EntityOptionalParameter>() })
        .Where(x => x.Attr != null); // Get all properties that have the attribute

    var sb = new StringBuilder("?");
    var first = true;
    foreach(var prop in props) // Loop through properties
    {
        if (first)
        {
            first = false;
        }
        else
        {
            sb.Append("&")
        }
        sb.Append(prop.Attr.ParameterName); // Append property name
        sb.Append("=");
        sb.Append(prop.Prop.GetValue(optionalParameter)); // Append property value
    }
    return sb.ToString()
}
```